# Access Crosstab Report Update Columns

Tags: ms-access, pivot, crosstab

I have a query running in MS Access which displays employees in the first column and then pivots the status of their training tasks in the remaining columns. Statuses are simply given as completed, not required or required as shown below:

```
Employee Computer Business Communication
=========================================
samiro05    C        NR         R
bobmarley   NR       NR         C
einstein    NR       R          R
```

With this query I can run a report and change the design to be better looking and conditionally formatted to highlight areas where training is required (R). If I add more people to the source tables along with their training I can press refresh on the report and it will add a new line for the employee name just as the crosstab query now has a new row for the new employee's training. However, if I add a new training task, say Science, and update the employees' training to include Science then my crosstab query looks like this:

```
Employee Computer Business Communication Science
=================================================
samiro05    C        NR         R           C
bobmarley   NR       NR         C           NR
einstein    NR       R          R           C
sheldon     C        C          R           C
```

...but my report when refreshed looks like this:

```
Employee Computer Business Communication
=========================================
samiro05    C        NR         R
bobmarley   NR       NR         C
einstein    NR       R          R
sheldon     C        C          R
```

Is there a way to get the columns of my crosstab query to change within my report as my crosstab query columns increase/decrease just by refreshing the report rather than having to create the whole report again each time I add a new training/each time a new column is added or taken away from my crosstab query?

Many thanks for any help you can give with this. I will add my thoughts on how to solve this in the comments below.

Comment: 1) Adding code to the report that upon refresh, the columns are reset whereby label and textbox for column 1 remain as employee but number of training tasks is counted and then that many labels and textboxes are added next to the employee column and with labels named after each row of the training task table and control sources for each textbox called by the training task name for the relevant column. E.G. labelN looking up name of row N of training task table and adds that as caption then textboxN looks up status of training for name of labelN and adds that as control source.

Comment: 2) This idea is not really a very exciting idea but it will solve the problem. If I change the crosstab query to pivot on employee rather than training task title (as I am more likely to add more training tasks than employees over the year) then I would just need a way to save the database report design or at least reuse it in the creation of a new report each time a new employee is added.

Comment: I have gone with my first idea. I have added 18 labels and 18 textboxes for 18 possible column headings. The code counts how many training tasks there are and then makes only that many labels and textboxes visible and renames the labels after the field names in the crosstab query along with adding the field name surrounded by "[" & "]" as a control source to the textboxes. This gives the impression that the report has refreshed to match the crosstab query. The only issue that I would face with this is when the column headings exceed 18 columns (which I anticipate will happen) so unfinished.